# How to extract a key pair value from a JSON array?

Tags: python, arrays, json, parsing, key-pair

I'm using a GET query string to locate a specific record. The correct result is returned in JSON, but in an array of one (it allows for multiple items, but as I'm using a unique key in my query string, there will only ever be one item returned, but's it's still in an array). I've been able to extract the value of a specific key pair from a JSON result before, but this time the fact that this particular result is in an array has got me stumped. I'm a set of square brackets away from success :-(
Here's the JSON response, and I want the value of 'Id':

```
{
'@odata.context': 'https://foo.bar.com/mySite/api/v2/object/$metadata#MuseuSensorData_SensorDeviceObject',
'value': 
    [
    {
     'Id': '02cb9c0f-89ca-46fd-882e-5d770d7da214',
     'DateCreated': '2022-07-13T14:05:22.24+01:00',
     'DeviceName': 'Cabinet 2 Sensor 1',
     'IsActive': True, 
     'SerialNumber': '1234'
   }
]}
```

In amongst my Python code, extract below, I'm trying to return the value of 'Id', but all I get is any one of a number of errors (latest is *TypeError: string indices must be integers*), which I know relates to indices/dictionaries and something called slices, and navigating through to the desired section, but I'm new to Python (as of this week), and it's got me spinning.

```
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
data = response.text
print(data[0]['value']['Id'])
```

Comment: `data['value'][0]['Id']`. You may also need `json.loads`, although here it looks like a python dict.

Comment: Thank you @KacperFloriański - changing the order, and using `json.loads`  worked!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was almost there. Thanks to [Kacper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8206522/kacper-floria%C5%84ski), I now have my code in the right order:

```
data = response.text
parsed_json = json.loads(data) 
RecID = parsed_json['value'][0]['Id']
print(RecID)
```